# How to make a change visible to one Class, if something was changed by another Class?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I'm trying to implement JButton as a Thread, and as I am not able to return JButton from the thread, I've created a new class `AllButtons` in which I store all the JButtons in an arrayList.

The problem is when I try to access my arrayList in `Build` class, the code gives me an exception as `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. However, it works when I access the same in `ButtonThread` class itself.

So how do I make change in `myList` visible in my `Build` Class considering I'm already passing object to ButtonThread constructor ?

Class AllButtons which contains an arrayList of JButton.

```
class AllButtons
{
   //new List
   List<JButton> myList = new ArrayList<JButton>();

   //add to List
   public void addMember(JButton button)
   {
     myList.add(button);
   } 

  //retrieve a particular value from List
   public JButton getButton(int index)
   {
     return myList.get(index);
   }

   //demo display
   public void display()
   {
     System.out.println(myList.get(0));
   }
}
```

Implementing Each Button as a Thread

```
class ButtonThread implements Runnable
{
    Thread t;

    int red, green, blue, number = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 255;
    AllButtons obj;

    ButtonThread(AllButtons obj, int number)
    {
       this.obj = obj;
       this.number = number;
       t = new Thread(this, "Color Thread" + this.number);
       t.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
       red = rand();
       green = rand();
       blue = rand();
       JButton button = new JButton("button");
       changeColor(button, red, green, blue);

       this.obj.addMember(button);
       this.obj.display();  //debug //print Jbutton  // this works!!
    }

    int rand(){
      return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max+1);
    }

    void changeColor(JButton btn, int red, int green, int blue)
    {
      btn.setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue));
    }

 }
```

Class Build

```
class Build
{
   //some code

   AllButtons ab = new AllButtons();

   Build()
   {

      /**
          JFrame code         **/

      //button

      new ButtonThread(ab, 1);  //make new button, object passed as well
      ab.display();  //here it fails,gives exception, list contains nothing, WHY ?

      JButton button1 = ab.getButton(0); //obviously this fails too


      /***********************/
      //JFrame Code//

   }
 }
```

Comment: 1) You should understand about `volatile` and `synchronized` before starting with multithreaded programming 2) "Swing's Threading Policy
In general Swing is not thread safe. All Swing components and related classes, unless otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event dispatching thread. " - this disclaimer is there for a reason :-)

Comment: @GyroGearless lovely lovely :D Thanks!
 btw I cannot mark a comment as an answer, so what should I do here ? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have a race condition. Welcome to multithreading!

Remember that as soon as you start up a second thread, you have NO IDEA when operations in that thread will occur, respective to your main thread, unless you synchronize them.

So what is likely happening (IMO) is that

1. Your constructor calls t.start() (so the "t" thread begins to start up)

...meanwhile, your code continues on the main thread, so it

2. Exits out of your constructor back into the Build method
3. Runs ab.display() (and throws an exception because ab is empty)
4. Tries to access ab[0] (and throws an exception because empty)

...after this has happened, the t thread has finally started up, so it

5. Runs and adds itself to ab.
6. Runs ab.display() successfully

As Gyro Gearless mentioned above - you REALLY need to read about synchronization and multithreading techniques in java. This is a really simple example of something going wrong, but when things get complex you are going to be totally lost unless you have a really good grasp on how to keep things threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

The handling of swing component is supposed to be done by the event dispatch thread. Do do something from another thread, you would use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) or [SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Even if I use <code>Swingutilities.invokeLarer</code>, it doesn't make a difference because of race conditions as mentioned by Gyro and Theodore